# Тире в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста: "Тире обычно не ставится, хотя подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именительным падежом существительного,
    в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи, например: "Моя сестра студентка".
    Видел в примерах предложение: "Моя мама - врач". В каких случаях в подобных предложениях нужно ставить тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) "Моя сестра студЕнтка. Она учится  институте". Паузы нет, интонация простого предложения  в разговорном стиле из рассказа "Моя семья".

(2) Диалог: Моя сестра учится в школе.  - А моЯ сестра - студЕнтка. Пауза, логическое ударение на первой части (не на второй!). (Смещение ударения на первую часть  как раз и дает возможность сделать паузу).

Таким образом, все зависит от текста. Есть такое понятие, как коммуникативность сообщения, или коммуникативное значение предложения. Разная интонация, разные знаки препинания позволяют не только передать смысл сообщения, но и обозначить речевую ситуацию.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы. Если можно,подскажите еще пожалуйста: Москва -столица нашей родины",и подобные предложения пишутся с тире в любом случае?По правилу:"Подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именительным падежом существительного"
И еще 1 вопрос: "Человек,которого я видел вчера _главный врач" Здесь нужна запятая или тире?

Answer (score 2):

В ваших примерах тире можно ставить, а можно опустить. 
Большой разницы в смысле нет. Тире нужно, если на сказуемое падает смысловое ударение (именно врач, а не медсестра), а если в разговорной речи, особенно быстрой устной, такого акцента не требуется (моя сестра, а не кто-то там еще) тире можно опустить, хотя можно и оставить.